# Delete / hide orchard authoring and date from content?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Is it possible to hide or delete the date and author that appears at the end of every content added to Orchard? I can't find any way to do that from the Dashboard :(

I have Orchard 1.6.0 and Bootstrap theme.

Below is an image of what I'm trying to quit / hide:

[image: Orchard author credits]

Thanks for the help. Have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide them by adding this to your theme's `Placement.info`:

```
<Match DisplayType="Detail">
    <Place Parts_Title="-"/>
    <Place Parts_Common_Metadata="-"/>
</Match>
<Match DisplayType="Summary">
    <Place Parts_Title="-"/>            
    <Place Parts_Common_Metadata="-"/>
</Match>
```

You can use Orchard's shape tracing feature to identify these parts and then show/hide them in your `placement.info`.

Comment: You're welcome. Try to search for and learn to use the shape tracing feature, it may seem weird initially but it puts you in control and makes Orchard a whole lot easier once you get the hang of it. Orchard is something that generally takes a lot of reading and practice.

Answer (score 0):

I too am playing with the Bootstrap theme and found that Mohammad's script hid more than was necessary as well as caused the content to start, hidden underneath the header.

The following, in {Theme Folder}/Placement.info, achieved the desired result as yenssen desired:

```
<Placement>
  <Match DisplayType="Detail">
    <!--<Place Parts_Title="-"/>-->
    <Place Parts_Common_Metadata="-"/>
  </Match>
  <Match DisplayType="Summary">
    <!--<Place Parts_Title="-"/>-->
    <Place Parts_Common_Metadata="-"/>
  </Match>
  ...
```